# Integration testing for a Spark Streaming application

Tags: sockets, apache-spark, integration-testing, spark-streaming, scalatest

I am trying to write the integration test for a complex spark streaming application, which has different input and output support.
After starting the application, a REST call is made which submits the json containing various Config params and component info. 
while I am trying to write the test case for socket as input and console as output I am pretty much confused as in how do I test the application as whole i.e submit the streaming data from the socket and then comparing the output from the console.

The application produces the output on the console itself via dataframe.println 
what is the approach to do the Integration testing?